# In LDA, after collapsed Gibbs sampling, how to estimate values of other latent variables?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I watched [a video on coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/bayesian-methods-in-machine-learning/lecture/RnMwB/mcmc-for-lda), everything went well until the following slide around 12'50''.
[image]

I read it in other papers that to estimate latent variables say $\Phi$ we can draw a sample $Z'$ of the full collection by collapsed Gibbs sampling and take $p(\Phi|W,Z')$ as an approximation.

This video says we can use $p(\Phi|W,\hat{Z})$ where $\hat{Z}$ is an average of a few samples.

My question is, does it make sense to average the samples of $Z$? If I understood correctly $z_{dn}$ represent the topic index that is responsible for the $n$th word in the $d$th document. But for two independent samples, the indices of the topics are not guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: You should write the equations, and not post a screenshot, here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346302/self-study-question-about-calculating-the-probability-random-variable  @Glen_b
explains why

Comment: @niandra82 thanks but I dont see how this is necessary here, the screenshot looks rather clear to me, even if it's for users who rely on screen readers there's link to the video with a lecturer who explains it better than a screen reader.

Comment: You have a (lot) higher reputation than me, so you are probably right. But I don't see why I should see the entire video to understand what $\theta$ or $Z$ are, for example. If you write the equations, you may be forced to explain what they represent. Just my opinion

Comment: @niandra82 if you're saying the equations need more explanation then that's a different problem which can not be improved by simply retyping all the equations, surely I'll try to add more explanation if i have time. Those who are familiar with lda should basically know what I'm asking only by the title so the screenshot is there to provide a common page of notations.

Answer (score 1):

The LDA has the following three latent variables:

1. $\phi_t$ - Topics - which are $W$ dimensional discrete distributions.
2. $\theta_d$ - per document topic proportions - which are $T$ dimensional discrete distributions.
3. $z_{d,n}$ which is the topic association of the $n$th word in the $d$th document ($w_{d,n}$). $z_{d,n} \in \{1, 2, ... T\}$.

Using collapsed Gibbs sampling, the topic allocations $z_{d,n}$ for words $w_{d,n}$ are sampled. Using these topic allocations, $\phi_t$ and $\theta_d$ can be estimated as follows:

$$
\phi_t(w) = \frac{n_j^{(w)}+\beta}{n_j^{(.)}+W\beta} \\
\theta_d(t) = \frac{n_j^{(d)}+\alpha}{n_.^{(d)}+T\alpha}
$$

where,

- $n_j^{(w)}:$ number of times $w^{th}$ word was assigned to topic $j$
- $n_j^{(.)}:$ total number of words assigned to topic $j$
- $n_j^{(d)}:$ number of times topic $j$ was assigned in $d^{th}$ document
- $n_.^{(d)}:$ total number of topics assigned in $d^{th}$ document
- $T:$ number of topics
- $W:$ number of words in vocabulary
- $\alpha, \beta:$ Dirichlet hyperparameters

Reference: [Griffiths et. al., (2004)](http://psiexp.ss.uci.edu/research/papers/sciencetopics.pdf)

Comment: Hi thank you that makes perfect sense, but actually I want to asked about the method in the video, how they average different samples of Z? If I understood correctly all the $n$s needed are computed based on one sample of the full collection $Z\in R^{W}$, the video mentioned about averaging different $Z$s and that's where I'm confused.

Comment: @dontloo you are correct that all the $n$'s are based on the topic assignments for the entire collection of documents. You don't really average over different $Z$'s. If you look at the implementation of the collapsed Gibbs sampler by the authors, nowhere do they average over $Z$'s.